# Making an image position relative to the top of the page

Tags: html, css

I have 2 images that I need to slightly overlap.  My first image is logo.png, and my second image is form.png

My html is:

```
<body id="wrapper">
  <div id="main" method="post" action="">
    <img src="images/logo.png" align="middle" id="Smarty" />
  </div>
  <div id="box" method="post" action="">
    <img id="Form" src="images/form.png" />
  </div>
```

And my CSS is:

```
 #wrapper #main {
   margin-top: 8%;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   text-align:center;
   display:block;
   z-index: 1;}

   #wrapper #box{
       margin-top: 8%;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   position: relative;
   text-align:center;
   top: 8%;
   display:block;
   z-index: -1;}
```

Basically I need both images to be centered relative to screen size, and I need the 2 to overlap.  With this code, both images center, but my form seems to be 8% down from my logo, rather than 8% down from the top of the screen.  Is this how I am supposed to be overlapping the 2, or am I way off?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of how you would like this to appear..

Comment: `<div id="box" method="post" action="">` - that's a funny looking `div`. I'm assuming you meant `form` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/6HBUw/)

Or using `position: absolute`, if that's what you want:
[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/6HBUw/3/)

**CSS:**

```
#main {
    margin: 8% auto 0 auto;
    text-align:center;

    /* 
      only include this next rule
      if you want the first image to be over the second
    */
    position: relative
}

#box {
    text-align: center;
    margin: -12px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main" method="post" action="">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x80/f0f/fff" align="middle" id="Smarty" />
</div>
<form id="box" method="post" action="">
    <img id="Form" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x40/f90/fff" />
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome - is there now a way I can place text and an input box on top of my form in the same method?

Comment: @Sapp: Which demo was the one you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following CSS code to do it. The 2 images will overlap each other and will be centered to the screen both horizontally and vertically.

```
#main, #box{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-150px; /* negative half the width of the image */
    margin-top:-150px; /* negative half the height of the image */
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/gVQc3/1/

If you want the images to overlap each other by certain amount of pixels, then see the following link.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/gVQc3/2/

Comment: That *might* be what he wants, but note that he said "I have 2 images that I need to **slightly** overlap".

Comment: My example includes 2 images.

Answer (score 1):

You should play around with fixed, static and absolute positions instead of relative.

See this link http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 1):

for the  #wrapper #box change the `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;`. This should fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you’re not doing anything that would make the images overlap each other.

For that to happen, you’d need to apply `position: absolute;` to them, and position them at the top of the page:

```
#wrapper #main,
#wrapper #box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

To horizontally center them when positioned absolutely, I think you’ll need to know their width. If they were both 100 pixels wide, you’d need:

```
#wrapper #main,
#wrapper #box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
```

I wouldn’t recommend a `z-index` of `-1` either, I don‘t think that makes sense. If you want `#main` to be on top, then I’d suggest:

```
#wrapper #main {
    z-index: 2;
}

#wrapper #box {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Note also that in your HTML, you’ve got `method` and `action` attributes on `<div>`s. These won’t have any effect: those attributes go on the `<form>` tag.